# ADB Shell input variable

Tags: python, shell, variables, input, adb

I want to inout a variable with ADB shell. However, i can't seem to find the right format for it to work. I tried a couple things but none of that quite worked.

```
aggr = open(r"xxx.txt", 'r')
content = aggr.readlines(1)
device.shell('input text "[content]"')
```

Comment: That is pure Python string manipulation. Just concat or format the string: `device.shell('input text "{}"'.format(content))`

Comment: You should specify what's in `content` as there might be edge cases

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Robert is right and it is indeed just pure python string manipulation.

```
device.shell('input text "{}"'.format(content))
```